# HDC memory leak (release HDC/ delete hdc)

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, gdi

I'm having trouble with this HDC memory leak. Could you guys check if I'm releasing/deleting HDC correctly?

Thank you!

```
BITMAP bm;
HBITMAP hbmap;
HBITMAP hBitmapOld;
BITMAPINFO bmi;
HDC hdcShot;
```

...

```
while(true)
{
    if (!TakeScreenshot(GameWindow, bm, hbmap, bmi, hdcShot, hBitmapOld, appWnd))
                    break;

        HBITMAP hbmapNew = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcShot, rcWindow.right - rcWindow.left, rcWindow.bottom - rcWindow.top);

        HDC hdcShotNew = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcShot);

        HBITMAP OldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcShotNew, hbmapNew);


        BitBlt(hdcShotNew, 0, 0, rcWindow.right - rcWindow.left/*Window WIDTH*/, rcWindow.bottom - rcWindow.top/*Window HEIGHT*/
            , hdcShot, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);


        pPixels = new RGBQUAD[bm.bmWidth * bm.bmHeight];
        if (!pPixels) return false;

        SelectObject(hdcShotNew, OldBmp);


        if (!GetDIBits(hdcShotNew, hbmapNew, 0, bm.bmHeight, pPixels, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
        {
            DeleteDC(hdcShot);
            delete[] pPixels;

            return false;
        }



// dont mind about this
        ScanContents scanContentsMain(bm, rcWindow, pPixels);
// dont mind about this
        ScanBMPHorizontal(&scanContentsMain);




        //free memory - I might have cleared the memory incorrectly here! Please check!
        free(pPixels);
        SelectObject(hdcShot, hBitmapOld);
                DeleteDC(hdcShot);
                DeleteObject(hbmapNew);
                DeleteDC(hdcShotNew);
}
```

TakeScreenShot Func (not really important but it shows how some variables are initialized)

```
    bool TakeScreenshot(std::string WindowToFind, BITMAP &bm, HBITMAP &hbmap, BITMAPINFO &bmi, HDC &hdcShot, HBITMAP &hBitmapOld, HWND &hwnd)
{
    RECT rc;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc);
    hdcShot = CreateCompatibleDC(0);
    hbmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(GetDC(0), rc.right - rc.left/*Window WIDTH*/, rc.bottom - rc.top/*Window HEIGHT*/);

    SelectObject(hdcShot, hbmap);


    BitBlt(hdcShot, 0, 0, rc.right - rc.left/*Window WIDTH*/, rc.bottom - rc.top/*Window HEIGHT*/
        , GetDC(0), rc.left, rc.top, SRCCOPY);

//Ignore this
    if (!GetObject(hbmap, sizeof(BITMAP), (LPSTR)&bm))
        return false;
    int bitsPerPixel = bm.bmBitsPixel;


 //Ignore this  
    if (bitsPerPixel != 32 || bm.bmPlanes != 1)
        return false;

//Don't mind about this too much 
    SetupBitmapInfo(bmi, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, bitsPerPixel);


    return true;

}
```

I checked with deleakers and found out that I'm struggling with HDC leak. I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

Comment: You are randomly calling different functions. This is deleting uninitialized variables, selecting uninitialized object in to DC, deleting other objects which are probably not supposed to be deleted. Does this code work at all?

Comment: It does. This is only a part of the full source code. It works pretty well actually. tiny bit of leaked memory is just added up over time.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Please look at my free memory functions. I think I might have freed the memory incorrectly. [ Added TakeScreenShot function]

Comment: You can use a `std::vector<RGBQUAD>` to store the pPixels without a raw pointer, it will manage the memory for you.

Comment: @MarianSpanik I will try that but most of the redundant high memory used over time is caused by HDC

Comment: You are showing partial code. I can tell it is wrong, but I don't have enough information to tell you how to fix it. I know this line is wrong `SelectObject(hdcShot, hBitmapOld)`. I am sure somewhere you are calling `GetDC`, `GetWindowDC`, or `BeginPaint`, but you are not calling the corresponding release function. Look at the documentation, it tells you for example to cleanup `GetDC` with `ReleaseDC`, not `DeleteDC`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani hdcShot is initialized by CreateCompatibleDC in TakeScreenShot Function. I will take a deeper look though. Ty for answering though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a resource leak here:

```
hbmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(GetDC(0), rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);
```

You should change to

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(0);
CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);
... 
ReleaseDC(0, hdc);//call this before exiting the function
```

`free(pPixels)` is wrong (although it still cleans up in this case). Replace `free(pPixels)` with `delete[]pPixels`

Change this:

```
SelectObject(hdcShot, hBitmapOld);
DeleteDC(hdcShot);
DeleteObject(hbmapNew);
DeleteDC(hdcShotNew);
```

To this:

```
SelectObject(hdcShot, OldBmp);
DeleteObject(hbmapNew);
DeleteObject(hBitmapOld);
DeleteDC(hdcShot);
DeleteDC(hdcShotNew);
```

Comment: I think this answer may sum it up. I will test it when I get back to my computer tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: Quoting this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224754/Guide-to-Win32-Memory-DC): _Always free the memory DC first, then the bitmap to avoid common resource leaks._ Not sure if it is likely to make any difference in this case, however.

Comment: @LaurieStearn That quote is nonsense, it's not how resource leaks occur. You have to follow Microsoft recommendations, which I have repeated. Call `SelectObject(hdcShotOldBmp)` first. Then call the Deletexxx functions. Deletexxx functions can be in any order.

Comment: @Barmak: I think his point is to place the `DeleteDC` statements before the `DeleteObject` statements. Just curious as to the motivation for this line of reasoning? Thanks.

Comment: @LaurieStearn That quote is wrong, I don't know what's the motivation behind it. You can ask the guy who wrote it. Otherwise refer to Microsoft documentation on this subject.